# Diagonalization of a generic matrix

Tags: matrices

Consider the following matrix

$$ M =\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a\, d\, s_1 \lambda_1 && a\, e\, s_1 \lambda_2&& a\, f\, s_1 \lambda_3\\
b\, d\, s_2 \lambda_1&& b\,e\, s_2 \lambda_2&&b\, f\, s_2 \lambda_3\\
c\, d\, s_3 \lambda_1&&c\, e\, s_3 \lambda_2&&c\, f\, s_3
\lambda_3\end{array}\right) $$
where *all* the entries are real.

Take the following symmetric matrix
$$
\tilde{M} = M \cdot M^T
$$

It has two zero and one different from zero eigenvalues.

If I use the usual procedure to find the orthogonal transformation to diagonalize $\tilde{M}$, that is
$$
O = \left(\begin{array}{c c c }
\vec{v}_1 & \vec{v}_2 & \vec{v}_3 
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $\vec{v}_{1,2,3}$ are the eigenvectors, I don't find an orthogonal matrix.
Just to be clear, 
$$
\vec{v}_{1} = (-\frac{f\,s_3}{d\, s_1},0,1 )\\
\vec{v}_{2} = (-\frac{e\,s_2}{d\, s_1},1,0 )\\
\vec{v}_{3} = (\frac{d\, s_1}{f s_3},\frac{e\, s_2}{f s_3},1)\\
$$
where $\vec{v}_{1,2}$ are associated to the zero eigenvalues and $\vec{v}_{3}$ to the non-zero one. Notice that $\vec{v}_{1,2}$ are not orthogonal.

Is the non-orthogonality of $O$ related to the fact that the eigenvectors associated to the zero eigenvalues are not orthogonal? I knew a theorem which states a symmetric real matrix is ALWAYS diagonalizable through a orthogonal rotation. My question is

How can I identify the right transformation in order to diagonalize $\tilde{M}$?

Comment: If your matrix truly is symmetric, then the eigenvectors should be orthogonal, and the eigenvectors are what form the columns of the orthogonal similarity transformation.

Comment: These are the eigenvectors I found with the help of Mathematica

Comment: And they turns out to be not orthogonal

Comment: @abmar I want to diagonalize $\tilde{M}$ not $M$!  $\tilde{M}$ is defined symmetric using the definition of $M$

Comment: I would double check your Mathematica code. The theorem you are referring to is sometimes called the "Spectral Theorem for Hermitian Matrices". It states that if $A$ is Hermitian (or symmetric), then there exists an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors which span the vector space the matrix is acting on.

Comment: What does in[1]:= $Assumptions do?

Comment: It tells to Mathematica kernel that the parameters are positive (and then real)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note is that the theorem only guarantees the existance of an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. In your case, you actually do have two orthogonal eigenvectors which correspond to the zero eigenvalue, but Mathematica does not return them. Any vector which is a linear combination of these two orthogonal eigenvectors (e.g., any vector which lies in the plane spanned by these two eigenvectors) will also be an eigenvector as well, and the algorithm that Mathematica uses to compute eigenvectors returns ones of these form. To see how to get orthogonalized eigenvectors, see this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72941/get-eigensystem-to-return-orthogonal-eigenvectors-for-hermitian-matrix.